# WHM/CPanel 11.42.1 with PHP 5.2.17 - Installing Freetype with GD

Tags: php, whm, freetype, freetype2

We have had to update Apache via EasyApache to 2.2+, and because of this, we could not install PHP 5.2 via EasyApache.

We have installed the standalone version of PHP 5.2.17 (legacy module) and manually enabled the Curl Extension – this all works correctly. Files are located in `/home/cpeasyapache/ ~ src ~ extensions` (or similar).

However, we cannot configure the `freetype/ttf` extension that a lot of our websites Captchas use. I really don’t know how best to include this (or -whether GD has to be re-compiled with it).

The version of GD is as follows:

```
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support     enabled
PNG Support     enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support     enabled
XBM Support     enabled
```

In a nutshell, I just need to add FreeType to this list, but the option to 'check a box' in easy-apache is no longer present as we're using a downgraded version of PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated!

David

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please install php 5.2 on your server through easyapache on your server using custom modules and then try to enable freetype with GD on your server.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Custom+Modules